# iOS Swift application instance time alive

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, appdelegate, cbcentralmanager

I have created an application that uses location services and bluetooth services.
Inside `AppDelegate` using significant location changes I am assigning a new instance of `CBCentralManager` like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    private static var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:  [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let keys = launchOptions?.keys {
            if keys.contains(.location) {
                AppDelegate.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
                locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral:CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {  
        AppDelegate.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)*
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        AppDelegate.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        AppDelegate.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)    
    }
}
```

How long is this instance staying alive? I am noticing that it may last even five days, but I am not sure which parameters affect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both significant location change notifications and BLE scan/connect notifications persist until cancelled. If your app is terminated by the os or there is a reboot, the system will re-launch your app to deliver them. There is no time limit on this.

This does not mean, however, that your app is guaranteed to keep running. It may be terminated as usual if there is resource pressure (or when the system feels like it; Apple has changed the algorithm a few times over the years). It will just be re-launched.

Regarding significant location changes, the [CLLocationManager docs explain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati#):

> If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new event arrives.

Regarding BLE, in order to continue scanning past a termination, you do need to implement State Preservation and Restoration for some cases. For details, see [Performing Long-Term Actions in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) in the Core Bluetooth Programming Guide. Connection requests similarly have no timeout. A connection request to a known device can run for weeks, and then re-launch your app when the device finally comes into range. This is an intentional feature and a supported use-case.

Significant location change notifications and BLE scanning/connecting are very low-power. They are typically performed by "piggybacking" on other operations. For example, significant location changes are often based on the phone switching cell towers; something it has to deal with already.

The side-effect, however, is that they are not promised to be highly responsive. For example, background BLE connection requests can take a minute or more to complete once the device comes into range, depending on how aggressively the device is advertising and whether it is using Apple's [recommended timings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1931/_index.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer, some clarifications would be helpful. When you say "If your app is terminated by the os or there is a reboot, the system will re-launch your app to deliver them. There is no time limit on this." The re-launch is done immediately ?

and when you say "Connection requests similarly have no timeout. " In order not to have timeout state preservation should be implemented?
Thanks

Comment: The relaunch will happen when the next event is delivered. So the app may not be launched for days or weeks (or ever) if the device never comes into range, or does not have a significant location change. There is never a specific connection timeout, but if you want to be relaunched after termination (or reboot) to handle it, you need to implement state preservation.